# is there an Event in Symfony 4 for when a user session expires?

Tags: symfony, session

I am building a web app with Symfony 4.2. 
I am currently trying to store the logout date of a user in a database in order to show him/her new contents since the last logout.
I have done that for when the user purposely clicks on logout, but I do not know how to achieve the same thing when his session expires. I tried looking for a Session expires Event in the official documentation of Symfony. The closest I could find was the following doc:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html

But I do not understand whether or not and how it could help me.
Is it possible to execute a function when the user session expires in Symfony 4 ?

Comment: Do you have remember_me function enabled on your symfony app?

Comment: No I did not enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session by its nature is a cookie that contains session id. It is, obviously, stored in browser and hence backend have no control over this cookie besides ability to get / set it. In other words there is no way for backend to catch **all possible cases** when session cookie may disappear on client. For example client may decline to store cookies or clear it manually.

Of course if you find at acceptable to treat every session as "session that is active until its lifetime will end from backend point of view" - there is quite simple way to achieve your goal:

1. There is [session cookie lifetime](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-cookie-lifetime) parameter into session configuration that is used to calculate expiration time of the session, you can either use it for calculating session expiration time
2. Alternatively you can listen for [`kernel.response`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html#the-kernel-response-event) event and check if session cookie is being set to take its expiration time directly.

If you will store this expiration time into user's account record - you will have exact information about session expiration. Use of this information may vary depending on your needs.